# Kotlin Error: Im a beginner in Kotlin programming and came up with this error

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Im a beginner in Kotlin programming and came up with this error my code is fine but when I compile it an error always occur:

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8686679909601592115, local class serialVersionUID = -5823904506976358318
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.incrementalCache_getModuleMappingData(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.RemoteIncrementalCacheClient.getModuleMappingData(RemoteIncrementalCacheClient.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalPackagePartProvider$moduleMappings$1.invoke(IncrementalPackagePartProvider.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalPackagePartProvider$moduleMappings$1.invoke(IncrementalPackagePartProvider.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalPackagePartProvider.findPackageParts(IncrementalPackagePartProvider.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment$binaryClasses$2.invoke(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment$binaryClasses$2.invoke(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.StorageKt.getValue(storage.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment.getBinaryClasses$descriptors_jvm(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope$kotlinScopes$2.invoke(JvmPackageScope.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope$kotlinScopes$2.invoke(JvmPackageScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.StorageKt.getValue(storage.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope.getKotlinScopes(JvmPackageScope.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope.getContributedClassifier(JvmPackageScope.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ChainedMemberScope.getContributedClassifier(ChainedMemberScope.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.AbstractScopeAdapter.getContributedClassifier(AbstractScopeAdapter.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.FileScopeFactory$currentPackageScope$1.getContributedClassifier(FileScopeFactory.kt:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(ResolutionScope.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.HierarchicalScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(Scopes.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ImportingScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(Scopes.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.FileScopeFactory$currentPackageScope$1.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(FileScopeFactory.kt:253)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.utils.ScopeUtilsKt.findFirstClassifierWithDeprecationStatus(ScopeUtils.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.QualifiedExpressionResolver.findClassifierAndReportDeprecationIfNeeded(QualifiedExpressionResolver.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.QualifiedExpressionResolver.resolveDescriptorForType(QualifiedExpressionResolver.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveDescriptorForType(TypeResolver.kt:932)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver$resolveTypeElement$1.visitUserType(TypeResolver.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitUserType(KtVisitorVoid.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitUserType(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtUserType.accept(KtUserType.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImplStub.accept(KtElementImplStub.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveTypeElement(TypeResolver.kt:245)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolvePossiblyBareType(TypeResolver.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveValueParameters(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:419)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.createValueParameterDescriptors(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:301)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.initializeFunctionDescriptorAndExplicitReturnType(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveFunctionDescriptor(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveFunctionDescriptor(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getDeclaredFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$getDeclaredFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$declaredFunctionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$declaredFunctionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNamedFunction.accept(KtNamedFunction.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.createFunctionDescriptors(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:282)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:204)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:554)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:545)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1479)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8686679909601592115, local class serialVersionUID = -5823904506976358318
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:715)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2161)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1685)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:457)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:270)
    ... 99 more
```

Comment: Also, I have to ask: if it gives an error, how do you _know_ that “my code is fine”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known Kotlin compiler bug, you can watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39474 for updates.

As a workaround, please rebuild the project, so incremental compilation caches are cleared.

Comment: Ohhh Great! Rebuilding the project worked. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, I've had this error before, try the following steps: *restart IntelliJ*, *restart PC / laptop*, *update IntelliJ*.

If the error still occurs, change under "*Project Structure*", "*Project SDK*" to any Java version click on "*Apply*", wait until the project has been successfully indexed, now switch the *"Project SDK*" back to Kotlin, click "*Apply*" again and wait again till the project has been successfully indexed.

The error should normally no longer occur.